# Use of @synthesize and value class type checking

Tags: objective-c, properties

This is probably a long shot, but I've got objects with a lot of properties.  The values of these objects are populated from NSDictionary's created from a database request.  Because of this, there may be `NSNull` values contained in those NSDictionaries that will automatically get assigned to the properties.  I need the properties to automatically discard values/objects that aren't of the correct type.  Currently I do it like this:

```
- (void) setViewID:(NSString *)viewID{
    if (!viewID || [viewID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) _viewID = viewID;
}
```

But that ends up being a lot of extra code when I've got 30-50 properties.  Is there a way to synthesize this behavior?  It seems like it would be a common enough requirement, but I can't seem to find a way to do it aside from writing it all out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not check for `NSNull` when you are going through the dictionary?  E.g.

```
for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    if (value == [NSNull null]) {
        value = nil;
    }
    [self setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Mostly because it's easier to filter NSNull at the property and NSNull isn't my only concern. There's quite a few methods that can take a NSDict and fill a particular object. Finding all those 'entry' points would be a PITA.  I've considered other design options, like having my database layer omit NULL items from the dict rather than add NSNull, but I'd need to really consider the impact of that on my program.  Also, I want the redundant protection my current code provides.  If my property receives a NSString when it should receive a NSNumber I want it to discard that instead of crashing.

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept this primarily because I don't think there's a way to do what I want and in the end I decided to omit `[NSNull null]` items and it worked well.  I suppose the lesson it that it's generally better and easier to omit NSNull altogether from NSDictionaries and instead check for nil, if necessary.